# How read in parallel all data from OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I want read all data from Orientdb database and I dont want get an iterator, I want read in some way all data in parallel by chunks from distinct pc across the network. There is any way to read database´s clusters in parallel or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the Spark connector for Orientdb, they query directly the clusters of the Orientdb classes in order to read the values of a complete class in parallel.

[Orient-Spark](http://orientdb.com/spark/)
[Git-code](https://github.com/metreta/spark-orientdb-connector)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PARALLEL in a SELECT query.

See: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query.html

PARALLEL Executes the query against x concurrent threads, where x refers to the number of processors or cores found on the host operating system of the query. You may find PARALLEL execution useful on long running queries or queries that involve multiple cluster. For simple queries, using PARALLEL may cause a slow down due to the overhead inherent in using multiple threads.

Comment: OK, that's interesting but I'm not asking for that, I'm sorry if it was not clear. I need to read from different pc pieces of data contained in OrientDb. Suppose I need to extract 20 GB of data and distribute it in 5 different pc's, in that case, I would like to assign 4GB portions to each pc and read them in distribute mode. It would be very helpful to be able to exploit the locality to not transmit unnecessary data over the network.